# My application crash after using Volley lib to retrieve ads Id

Tags: android, admob

I modified my project code to retrieve admob id from a server to show admob banner/interstitial using particular value of id by volley lib. Consequently, my application crashes each time the interstitial starts

The logcat points that "**The ad unit ID must be set on InterstitialAd before loadAd is called.**"

This warning is caused by

```
 @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (!isRedirected || INCREMENT_WITH_REDIRECTS) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                webViewCount = webViewCount + 1;
                if (webViewCount >= ServerClass.SHOW_AD_AFTER_X) {
                    if (ServerClass.SHOW_FULL_SCREEN_AD && !HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE) {
                        if (ServerClass.USE_FACEBOOK_ADS) {
                            if (facebookInterstitialAd != null) {
                                facebookInterstitialAd.loadAd();
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                                final AdRequest fullscAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(fullscAdRequest);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So when I change it to

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                                final AdRequest fullscreenAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ServerClass.interstitial_full);
                                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(fullscreenAdRequest);
                            }
```

I got another warning "**The ad unit ID can only be set once on InterstitialAd.**"

since setAdUnitId is already used in an if statement in onCreate method:

```
        if (!HIDE_PURCHASE) {
            if (ServerClass.FACEBOOK_ADS) {
                  //CODE
            } else {
                mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ServerClass.interstitial_full);

                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {

                        showInterstitial();
                    }

                });
            }
```

How could I prevent my app from crashing, and why is retrieving data from server would cause that though the data is already present based on Log msg